# Select a Range and Sort

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

I have the following Word Document that I can add Test information:

Outline View (Level 2):

Table of Contents

List of Figures

Abbreviations

1. Section Name

1.1 Test-01

1.2 Test-08

1.3 Test-02

etc...

The tests are not always done in order and I want to sort the 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc so it will be like this:

1. Section Name

1.1 Test-01

1.2 Test-02

1.3 Test-08

etc...

This is what I have so far:

```
word_doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdOutlineView;
word_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading(2);
```

I need to select the 1.1 to the end of the document here and I don't know how...

```
word_app.Selection.Sort (false, ref FieldNumber, Word.WdSortFieldType.wdSortFieldAplphanumeric, Word.WdSortOrder.wdSortOrderAscending, ref missing, ...etc.)

word_app.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;
```

I did created a bookmarkstart at the 1.1 heading and another bookmarkstop at the end of the document.  I can now select the text with the following line, however the bookmarkerstart will no longer be present when the sort function is completed...

```
object oBookmarkStart = "Bookmark_Start";
object oStart = word_doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkStart).Range.Start;

object oBookmarkStop = "Bookmark_Stop";
object oStop = word_doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkStop).Range.Start;

Word.range rngBKMARKSelection = word_doc.Range(ref oStart, ref oStop);
```

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (might not be the best, but it works!) :

word_doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdOutlineView;
word_doc.ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading(2);

word_app.Selection.Find.set_Style(word_doc.Styles[styleHeading2]);
word_app.Selection.Find.Execute();

object oBookmarkStart = "\StarOfSelection";
object oStart = word_doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkStart).Range.Start;

object oBookmarkStart = "\EndOfDoc";
object oStop = word_doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookmarkStop).Range.Start;

Word.Range rngBKMarkSelection = word_doc.Range(ref oStart, ref oStop);
rngBKMarkSelection.Select();

word_app.Selection.Sort (false, ref FieldNumber, Word.WdSortFieldType.wdSortFieldAplphanumeric, Word.WdSortOrder.wdSortOrderAscending, ref missing, ...etc.)

word_app.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;

Answer (score 0):

I'm typing the C# off the top of my head, so no guarantees that the syntax is exactly right, but if not you should be able to derive it from the following example. According to my quick test the RANGE is retained after the sort. So all you need to do is recreate a (new) bookmark:

```
object oRngBookmark = rngBKMARKSelection;
Word.Bookmark bkm = word_doc.Bookmarks.Add("sortedRange", ref oRngBookmark);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found a way to use the predefine bookmark in word...it might not be the best way, but it work for now :-)

Comment: Probably, what I suggested is faster, if you measure things in micro-seconds. But if the action doesn't repeat numerous times you'll certainly not notice any difference :-)